# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_19 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (5, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have the following code that creates LSTM network using Keras with TensorFlow backend.
This code runs well.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import model_selection
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.utils import np_utils

flights = {
            'flight_stage': [1,0,1,1,0,0,1],
            'scheduled_hour': [16,16,17,17,17,18,18],
            'delay_category': [1,0,2,2,1,0,2]
        }

columns = ['flight_stage', 'scheduled_hour', 'delay_category']

df = pd.DataFrame(flights, columns=columns)

X = df.drop('delay_category',1)
y = df['delay_category']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

nb_features = X_train.shape[1]
nb_classes = y.nunique()
hidden_neurons = 32
timestamps = X_train.shape[0]

# Reshape input data to 3D array
X_train = X_train.values.reshape(1, X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1])
X_test = X_test.values.reshape(1, X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1])

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(
                units=hidden_neurons, 
                return_sequences=True, 
                input_shape=(timestamps,nb_features)
              )
         )

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(activation='softmax', units=nb_classes))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer='adadelta')
```

But when I start training the model, it fails:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.25, epochs=500, batch_size=2, shuffle=True, verbose=0)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_19 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (5, 3)
```

This error refers to the final Dense layer. I used `model.summary()` to get exact dimensions. The output shape of a Dense layer is `(None, 5, 3)`. 
However I do not understand why does it have 3 dimensions and what `None` stands for (how did it appear in this last layer)?

Comment: What is the shape of the features and labels data ?

Comment: @edkeveked: The shape is the following: `X_train shape: (1, 5, 2)`, `X_test shape: (1, 2, 2)`, `y_train shape: (5,3)`, `y_test shape: (2,3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 is the number of units returned by the last layer. It is the number of classes for the softmax activation

5 is the number of units returned by the lstm which indicates the size of the sequences returned

None is the number of element by batch for the last layer. It simply means that the last layer can accept different size for each batches of tensor of shape [5, 3]

```
X_train shape: (1, 5, 2), 
X_test shape: (1, 2, 2), 
y_train shape: (5,3), 
y_test shape: (2,3)
```

Looking at the data shape, there is clearly a mismatch between the batchsize of the features and that of the labels. The most left number should be equal between the features shape X and the labels shape y. It is the batchsize.

```
'1', 5, 2 => batch size of 1
'2', 3 => batch size of 2
```

There is a mismatch here.
Also to solve the issue between the output of the lstm layer and the input of the last layer, one can use a `layer.flatten`

```
nb_classes = 3
hidden_neurons = 32

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(
                units=hidden_neurons, 
                return_sequences=True, 
                input_shape=(5, 2)
              )
         )

model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(activation='softmax', units=nb_classes))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer='adadelta')

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam')
```

[live code](https://repl.it/@kedevked/keras-Lstm)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Could you please indicate how to solve my issue? I think that all numbers in my code correctly fit your definitions. Therefore I cannot catch what am I doing wrong.

Comment: @ingrid, I edited my question. Tell me if there are things left to explain

Comment: Thanks, I completely understood why this error happens. However, I still do not understand how to solve it. If the solution is to use `layer.flatten`, could you please show how it works using my code sample?

Comment: Does it really work for you? I get this error for the input data that I published in my question: `ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 5 target samples.`

Comment: The batches should be of same size. Change your label shape y to be (1, 3). See the kind of shape I used for my working code. Also, bear in mind that the X_train and X_test should have their data shape to match the input shape of the model. The X shape can be (1, 5, 2)